# How can I reliably load and display images from ID3 tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mp3, id3

I'm trying to display an image loaded from ID3 and ID3v2 files.

I'm able to get all of the tag fields off of ID3 and ID3v2 files, and I get back the picture as big string of data. I've tried doing something like:

```
var image = 'data:image/png;base64,' + (tags.picture);
```

And creating an image element, but that doesn't work.

So I'm wondering, is the image data in an ID3 tag not necessarily base64? And if so, perhaps I'm not reading the format of the image correctly?

I'm new to working with this sort of file, so any hints or tips would be amazing.

Comment: Why do you assume that the ID3 image data is base64-encoded?

Comment: I had thought it might work like a data uri and actually that seems to work with images loaded from id4s.

Comment: there is no image data in ID3 tags, which are only 128bytes long, nowhere near enough for text and image data!

Comment: Are you sure? There seems to be some kind of image that can be stored http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_Embedded_Image_Extension

Such as the preview image you can see in most OS if the cover has been embedded.